# How to dismiss ProgressDialog in Volley and Internet connection error handling

Tags: javascript, android, progressdialog, android-volley

I am trying to create this Volley project as my second activity which fetches a JSON feed from Yahoo Pipe and display in a `ListView` from [here](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html?m=1). The code works perfectly fine. However, I have encountered these problems:

When I have not turned the Internet on, the activity displays the loading `ProgressDialog`. However, pressing the Back button on my emulator or actual device does not dismiss the `ProgressDialog`. The activity did not respond to the Back action.

I tried this code, but it does not work or maybe I'm not doing it right:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    dismissPd();
}

private void dismissPd() {
    if (pd != null) {
        pd.dismiss();
        pd = null;
    }
}
```

In case of an Internet connection error, how do I display the error message in this activity as a toast?

The following is my code:

```
public class Trending extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private ListView lstView;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<NewsModel> arrNews ;
    private LayoutInflater lf;
    private VolleyAdapter va;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trending);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent newActivity3=new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity3);
        lf = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        arrNews = new ArrayList<NewsModel>();
        va = new VolleyAdapter();
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lstView.setAdapter(va);
        mRequestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://pipes.yahooapis.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=giWz8Vc33BG6rQEQo_NLYQ&_render=json";
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading...","Please Wait...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(Exception e) {

    }
    JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
            parseJSON(response);
            va.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i(TAG,error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(jr);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dismissPd();
    }
    private void dismissPd() {
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
            pd = null;
        }
    }
    private void parseJSON(JSONObject json){
        try {
            JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject("value");
            JSONArray items = value.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i=0; i<items.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
                NewsModel nm = new NewsModel();
                nm.setTitle(item.optString("title"));
                nm.setDescription(item.optString("description"));
                nm.setLink(item.optString("link"));
                nm.setPubDate(item.optString("pubDate"));
                arrNews.add(nm);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    class NewsModel {
        private String title;
        private String link;
        private String description;
        private String pubDate;
        void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }
        void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
        void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
        }
        String getLink() {
            return link;
        }
        String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        String getPubDate() {
            return pubDate;
        }
        String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }
    class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrNews.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return arrNews.get(i);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
           ViewHolder vh;
           if (view == null) {
               vh = new ViewHolder();
               view = lf.inflate(R.layout.row_listview,null);
               vh.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
               vh.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
               vh.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
               view.setTag(vh);
           } else {
               vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
           }    
           NewsModel nm = arrNews.get(i);
           vh.tvTitle.setText(nm.getTitle());
           vh.tvDesc.setText(nm.getDescription());
           vh.tvDate.setText(nm.getPubDate());
           return view;
        }
        class  ViewHolder {
            TextView tvTitle;
            TextView tvDesc;
            TextView tvDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i use mProgressDialog.dismiss(); on catch or within onPostExecute if use asyncTask

Comment: @AndresCardenasPardo so i should get rid of the  `onDestroy`method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one then back button is working while dialog is running

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading...","Please Wait...");
pd.setCancelable(true);
```

By use asynctask you write code like this way

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, null, "fetching ...");
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
       //fetch response from internet and process here


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pd.cancel();
      //do next action here

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the JSON part of the code in AsyncTask.

Define doInBackground to return a String type. From doInBackground, handle the errors, like internet error or json error and accordingly return a suitable error message "internet error" or "json error".

This error will be available as input to onPostExecute (results). In onPostExecute, you can run a Switch Statement to handle each of the conditions. If "internet error", then pd.dismiss() and do a toast.

For a working version of the code, you can refer [here...](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/first-android-app-step-3-getting-data.html)